# Open cvtColor is too slow in Color Detection

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to detect color from a continuous IP Camera input, but the `cvtColor` is making the code really slow. Is there a way to directly detect colors from the live video without converting the **RGB** to **HSV**? Here's my code -

```
VideoCapture capture(The address of camera);
...
while (true)
{
    Mat frame;
    if (!capture.read(frame))
        break;
    imshow("Live Video", frame);
    Mat imgHSV;
    cvtColor(frame, imgHSV, COLOR_BGR2HSV); // <- This code makes the app sloooow !!!
    Mat imgThresholded;
    inRange(imgHSV, Scalar(lowH, lowS, lowV), Scalar(highH, highS, highV), imgThresholded);
    imshow("Thresholded Image", imgThresholded);
}
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Did you try preallocating imgHSV matrix? Sometimes memory allocation is the slowest thing.

Comment: @JakaKonda How should I preallocate imgHSV matrix? By placing it before the `while` loop?

Comment: Yes, that should do the trick since OpenCV knows how to recycle things. Also I noticed it now, but try doing the same with `frame`. Something like `Mat imgHSV, frame; while(true) { code }`

Comment: @JakaKonda I tried to preallocate, but the improvement in speed wasn't much. Any other ideas?

Comment: One more, gonna try it on my PC first. What kind of performance penalty do you get? Is it by a factor of 2, 3?

Comment: @JakaKonda , The display comes 7-10 seconds after the picture is taken on camera, and if I use my built-in webcam, the delay is of 3-6 seconds.

Comment: What's your image resolution? do you compile in release mode?

Comment: use cv::waitKey(1); after cv::imshow

Comment: Image resolution - 640x480, and no, I compiled in Debug mode

Comment: the last one in the block. so the threshold one.

Comment: @Micka tried it, but had no special effect on the speed.

Comment: try in release mode please.

Comment: @Micka Wow, release mode reduced the delay to 1-2 seconds! (Between Google Chrome view of camera and my app's camera) Can the delay be reduced a little more?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104089/discussion-between-blazingfire-and-micka).

Comment: Still looks very slow. But no idea how to improve further...

Comment: Wow, those delays are huge. No matter what I did it worked real time on my PC without any significant penalties. Glad you managed to get it working!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Micka and Jaka Konda, I could reduce the delay to the minimum. First I preallocated the `Mats` by placing them before the `While` loop. Then, compiled the app in `Release` mode. This steps greatly improved the speed.

**UPDATE -**

I found another method by which speed can be increased by a thousand times - Use CUDA OpenCV. (It can be used with Visual Studio 2015, even with Visual Studio 2013 libraries).